# Get option value in multiple select tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++ ){?>
    <tr id="row">
      <td class="input-field col s2">
       <label>Week Days</label>
        <select id="week_days<?php echo $i;?>" data-rel="chosen" name="week_days<?php echo $i;?>[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="1">Monday</option>
                <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                <option value="5">Friday</option>
                </select>
              </td>   
                </tr>
   <?php } ?>
<a id="more_btn" class="right" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="../../assets/images/icons/add-icon.ico" width="23px" title="Add More"/></a>
```

How to get the value of option using jquery?

issue is that I am getting a null on click anchor tag. Waht is the right way to getting option value. First user select a Monday option and click on add more anchor tag then in alert show 1 value that is correct but when user change a option and click on add more anchor tag then alert show it null. why it show null instead of 1,2,3,4,5?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var j=1;
 $('#more_btn').click(function() {
   j++;
   var u = j-1;
   var prev_weekdays = $('#week_days'+u).val();
   alert(prev_weekdays);
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Do you want to loop through the option element or the select element?

Comment: Choose an option first from your dropdown then click your add button.

Comment: @Jeto you have a solution of this problem?

Comment: Well it works with plain html in JSFiddle. Can you check the html code that your php generate? Did you tried to debug it?

Comment: And what do you mean by "but when user change a option and click" ? There is 5 select boxes with those day options, so you can select different days in those and then 5 times click "Add More" button. Is that what you want?

Comment: check my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584516/issue-of-getting-option-value-when-record-is-exist-in-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue of getting option value when record exists in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584516/issue-of-getting-option-value-when-record-exists-in-database)

Comment: Why you did duplicate question? Remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

When the more_btn link click get the selected value of weekdays and alert it see the example 
Ex -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#more_btn').click(function() {
    var prev_weekdays = $('#week_days').find(":selected").text();
    alert(prev_weekdays);
 });
 </script>
```

make the your select as

```
<select id="week_days" data-rel="chosen"  class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">Monday</option>
            <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="4">Thursday</option>
            <option value="5">Friday</option>
            </select>
```

Tell me if this is Working or not

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will resolve  your issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Get Values from Multiple Select Box</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function(){
    var countries = [];
    $.each($(".country option:selected"), function(){            
        countries.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert("You have selected the country - " + countries.join(", "));
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Press control key (Ctrl) to select multiple values:</p>
<form>
    <label>Country:</label>
    <select class="country" multiple="multiple" size="5">
        <option value="1">United States</option>
        <option value="2">India</option>
        <option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="4">Brazil</option>
        <option value="5">Germany</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button">Get Values</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```